# Grunt.js использование на реальном сайте

Tags: grunt

Нашел в интернете инструкцию по тому как сжать css либо js на сайте для ускорения загрузки.
Нашел даже ссылку с видео.
https://www.ru.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Drugie-vebinary/Hakaton-v-pryamom-efire-Uskoryaem-mobilnye-sayty/ba-p/372116

Проблемма в том что я не понимаю как они там устанавливают этот файл и вообще откуда запускают консоль.

Понял что нужно скачать node.js я его скачал.
Запускал консоль через win+R => cmd.exe.

Но как работать с сайтом который лежит на хостинге?
В видео выше по ссылке на 46ой минуте все легко делают.
Но мне кажется там есть недосказания.
Может кто-то помочь и обьяснить как настроить такую компиляцию на сервере?

Comment: Компилируют локально, а скомпилировнный файл закидывают на сервер

Comment: А как потом сказать интернет браузеру чтобы он не грузил те 5 файлов js а вместо них грузил один скомпилированый js файл еще с другим адресом?

Comment: Ну а как вы файлы js подключаете? Подключите вместо них скомпилированный один файл. То есть, изменити html

Comment: У меня сайт на Wordpress. И те скрипты подключаются с помощью плагинов, и зависят от плагинов.
Я так понимаю поставлю плагин другой, и просто запрещу к загрузке эти скрипты, а вместо них в <body> подключу тот скомпилированный.

Comment: На WordPress следует использовать wp_dequeue_script() и wp_enqueue_script()

Comment: На самом деле у меня больше тормозов из-за css стилей. Я так понимаю сначала мне нужно скомпелировать все стили в один файл. 
После этого я хуком wp-dequeue_style() не буду загружать определенные стили, но вместо них буду загружать хуком wp_enqueue_style() тот свой минифицированный.
А что мне делать с тем что стили подгружаются вместе с версией. Например так как ниже....Мне просто игнорировать ?ver=2.1.2 и все будет работать? 
https://мой-сайт/wp-content/plugins/content-views-query-and-display-post-page/public/assets/css/cv.css?ver=2.1.2

Comment: Версия ничего не означает, кроме версии. wp_dequeue_script() отменит запуск независимо от версии. Вы документацию почитайте. Там важен только hadle - первый аргумент

Answer (score 0):

Для `WP` советую бесплатный плагин `Autoptimize`, так как это там меньше разбираться чем с `Grunt` а результат очень хороший. Официальная страница [плагина](https://autoptimize.com/). Так же хороший урок по `Grunt` - [тут.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cxo1vVI9--E)

Comment: Спасибо большое.